# Is it possible to use normal order evaluation in F#

Tags: f#, operator-precedence

In Scala you can choose between applicative or normal order evaluation, see “[Scala call-by-name (=>) vs call-by-type](http://omgo.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/scala-call-by-name-vs-call-by-type/)” for an example.

```
  def byName(a: => Unit) = {
    for (i <- 0 until 10) {println(a)}

  }

  def byValue(a: Unit) = {
    for (i <- 0 until 10) {println(a)}

  }

  var i = 1;

  byValue(i = i + 1)
  println(i); // 2

  byName(i = i + 1)
  println(i) // 12
```

Is the same possible in F# ?

Answer (score 4):

As Lee pointed out, F# does not let you specify the evaluation strategy for arguments of functions. This is certainly a useful feature, but I think it may be sometimes confusing - for example if you have a first-class function like `int -> int`, then the type does not tell you what evaluation strategy to use, so you either have to make types more complex or restrict this to named functions.

Aside from working with lambda functions explicitly, F# also provides support for lazy evaluation (that is, evaluate lazily, but cache the result) using the `lazy` keyword and `Lazy<'T>` type:

```
let foo (a:Lazy<int>) (b:Lazy<int>) = 
  if a.Value = 0 then 0
  else b.Value
```

This function will evaluate the second argument only if the first one is non-zero:

```
foo (lazy (printfn "a"; 0)) (lazy (printfn "b"; 10))   // Prints just 'a'
foo (lazy (printfn "a"; 10)) (lazy (printfn "b"; 10))  // Prints both 'a' and 'b'
```

This is a bit more syntactically light-weight than using functions, but it still requires explicit specification on the call-site and not just on the declaration-site.

Comment: That's a pretty cool way of using lazy to "simulate" some kind of call-by-name.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's no built-in support for this, so the closest you can get is to emulate it by delaying the computation with a function.

```
let cnst a b = a
let apply (f: unit -> unit) = Seq.iter (fun i -> printfn "%A" (f())) [1..10]
let byName (f: unit -> unit) = apply (cnst (f()))
let byValue (f: unit -> unit) = apply f
```

Then your example would be:

```
let i = ref 1
byValue (fun _ -> do i := !i + 1)

printfn "%d" !i

i := 1
byName (fun _ -> do i := !i + 1)
printfn "%d" !i
```